# Создание браузера на с++ в рамках обучения

Tags: c++, браузер

Доброго времени суток!

Я занимаюсь самостоятельным и изучением С++ (Microsoft Visual C++): учусь, делая что-то для винды. Например, пеинт, блокнот или простенькие игры.
Я хочу в рамках обучения написать свой интернет-браузер. Я не претендую на роль первооткрывателя чего-либо, я просто хочу во всём этом разобраться без готовых решений вроде "установи C++ Builder, добавь веб-движок, часик поколдуй над компонентами и вуаля!". Я хочу разобраться и написать всё (в пределах разумного) с нуля.

Функции, которые должен выполнять самописный браузер - все обычные для обычного пользователя - просмотр веб-страниц, автозаполнение форм, масштабирование, менеджер загрузок, история и поддержка Unity Web Player и Flash Player.

Найти нужную информацию я могу и сам, но я ничего не понимаю в терминологии - иначе говоря, я не знаю что именно хочу найти. Подскажите, в каких направлениях мне нужно копать и какие страшные-непонятные термины гуглить? Если на эту тему уже есть хорошие источники - форумы, книги или статьи - дайте ссылку.

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Чего там мелочиться, пишите сразу собственную операционную систему!

Comment: Начните с протокола HTTP (В гугле искать HTTP RFC) и стандартов HTML первоисточник где то на http://w3.org Собственно этого достаточно. Все остальное это всякие winapi функции в основном для визуализации. Ну и надеюсь вы понимаете что браузер с описанным вами функционалом команда квалифицированных разработчиков с нуля будет писать несколько лет

Comment: В том-то и дело, что не понимаю, а потому и не понимаю объём работ. В книгах есть либо самое простое, либо слишком сложное, понять которое меня пока что ещё не хватает. Быть очередным 100500м умельцем собрать готовое из готового - неплохо, но без понимания основ - не лучшее из возможных.

Comment: В браузере есть, например, интерпретатор JavaScript. Сделать его самостоятельно - тоже очень сложно. Но можете сделать какой-нибудь свой язык и интерпретатор для него. Для обучения - неплохая задача. Потом, как вам там ниже отвечают, в браузере есть HTTP-клиент. Сделайте отдельно клиент, многое поймете. Сделайте сервер, тоже полезно будет.

Comment: Flash Player - перестал поддерживатся в хроме - и... скорее всего прекратит своё существование.

Answer (score 3):

Основные компоненты браузера - это HTTP-клиент, плюс "построитель" DOM-дерева с реализацией его стандарта, визуализация (рендеринг) дерева, то есть сама отрисовка элементов, и "движок" для CSS и JS (интерпретатор с библиотекой, опять же реализующей стандарты), остальное является дополнительными компонентами и намного проще и менее объемно, там могут быть и FTP, и POP3/IMAP/SMTP (почта), и расширения, плагины, и менеджер загрузок, опять же основа скачивания файлов это HTTP и т.п.

Работа огромна, исходный код Chromium "весит" гигабайты, вам придется потратить очень много времени и энергии, а практического применения нет, пользы обществу нет, разве что в будущем продать как курсовую или дипломную работу, но эти работы должны писаться быстро, ровно столько, сколько нужно для их успешной защиты в ВУЗе, ничего большего студенты не заслуживают за свои деньги, да и на самом деле не нужно, в общем, человеку в обществе надо удовлетворять реальным требованиям общества, а не своим фантазиям.

Comment: Извините, но как технарь я не понимаю слова "много". Много - это сколько - месяц, год, десять лет? Пол года-год-два было бы ещё терпимо..если бы я делал в коммерческих целях. А мне нужно только для того, что бы понимать как всё устроено. Конечно, можно почитать умных статеек и сделать вид, будто я всё понял - но пока не сделаю хоть что-то, ничего не пойму. И мне показалось, что браузер - адекватный вариант.

А на счёт Chronium-a - разве там исключительно всё нужное? Наверняка там есть "всё для всех случаев", а реально нужная часть будет весить куда меньше - так мне кажется, или я не прав?

Comment: @lolifrag Только вот вот те "обычные" функции, типа просто просмотра страницы и есть 90% всего что делает браузер. Сколько времени у вас уйдет что бы набрать с кравиатуры гигабайт текста ? Только этот текст предварительно надо будет продумать, а потом отладить ...

Comment: @lolifrag Чтобы понимать, как все устроено, следует изучать то, что устроено. По-вашему, в мире нет людей, у которых проблемы с версткой, JS, Angular, с расширением для браузера, и которым нужна ваша помощь и в процессе практики ее оказания вы изучите эти технологии? Все необходимое есть, но глупые люди выбирают худшее. Насчет объемов, почитайте какой-нибудь htmlbook.ru, вот это все вам нужно реализовать, можно и не все, но тогда получится такой браузер, как IE 5 и даже хуже.

Comment: @lolifrag Дело в том, что 95% того что делает браузер - это просто муторная работа по разбору HTML с соблюдением уймы стандартов, определение координат объектов и т.п. А для понимания как все устроено нужно совсем другое - надо знать как работает сеть в целом, т.е. стек протоколов TCP/IP, DNS, прочитать про основы протокола HTTP. Зная только URL отправить правильный запрос web-серверу и получить от него ответ. Дальше - другие разделы программирования, синтаксический анализ, визуализация. И мало кому нужно все это сразу

Comment: @Mike хм.. действительно, мне это тоже не нужно..

Comment: @lolifrag Поэтому если хотите понимать как работает основа интернета - дойдите до стадии "получил и записал в файл данные полученные от web-сервера по заданному URL". Ну может куки отдельно сохраните и при следующем обращении к тому же сайту умейте их отдать. А потом найдите какие нибудь другие, не такие объемные и более разнообразные задачи.

Comment: @Mike Почему же только HTTP, знать стоит всего перечисленного по-немногу, вот это будет полезно людям, в отличие от создания очередного браузера-pet-project'а.

Comment: А самое забавное, к тому моменту когда Вы напишете свой браузер, текущие языки разметки видоизменятся, появятся новые фишки и... чего уж там мелочиться, пишите сразу операционную систему, как заметили выше :)

Answer (score 2):

Работа не то чтобы огромна, она почти невыполнима для хорошего программиста (возможно через 10 лет напишет браузер), ну уж для новичка-то тем более.

Есть возможность использовать встроенный компонент, который позволяет использовать браузер. Но это уже браузер и вы будете пользоваться готовым решением. Работа сведется к изучению небольшой инструкции по подключению.

Если вы хотите создать что-то свое, то начните с чего куда проще: сперва определитесь с тем что вам интересно (например браузер). Задача куда проще - научиться парсить строки. Пробуйте парсить что ли, если вам интересно) Я сам начинал с написания игр, мне игры было интересно делать)